# How to execute an async fetch request and then retry last failed request?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

[Apollo link offers an error handler `onError`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-error#retrying-failed-requests)

**Issue:**
Currently, we wish to refresh oauth tokens when they expires during an apollo call and we are unable to execute an async fetch request inside the `onError` properly.

**Code:**

`initApolloClient.js`

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { ApolloLink, fromPromise } from 'apollo-link';

//Define Http link
const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
    uri: '/my-graphql-endpoint',
    credentials: 'include'
});

//Add on error handler for apollo link

return new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward  }) => {
            if (graphQLErrors) {
                //User access token has expired
                if(graphQLErrors[0].message==="Unauthorized") {
                    //We assume we have both tokens needed to run the async request
                    if(refreshToken && clientToken) {
                        //let's refresh token through async request
                        return fromPromise(
                            authAPI.requestRefreshToken(refreshToken,clientToken)
                            .then((refreshResponse) => {
                                let headers = {
                                    //readd old headers
                                    ...operation.getContext().headers,
                                    //switch out old access token for new one
                                    authorization: `Bearer ${refreshResponse.access_token}`,
                                };

                                operation.setContext({
                                    headers
                                });

                                //Retry last failed request
                                return forward(operation);
                            })
                            .catch(function (error) {
                                //No refresh or client token available, we force user to login
                                return error;
                            })
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}),
```

What happens is:

1. Initial graphQL query runs and fails due to unauthorization
2. The `onError` function of `ApolloLink` is executed.
3. The promise to refresh the token is executed.
4. The `onError` function of `ApolloLink` is executed again??
5. The promise to refresh the token is completed.
6. The initial graphQL query result is returned and its data is `undefined`

Between step 5 and 6, *apollo doesn't re-run the initial failed graphQL query* and hence the result is `undefined`.

**Errors from console:**

```js
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Error writing result to store for query:
 query UserProfile($id: ID!) {
  UserProfile(id: $id) {
    id
    email
    first_name
    last_name
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

The solution should allow us to:

1. Run an async request when an operation fails
2. Wait for the result of the request
3. Retry failed operation with data from the request's result
4. Operation should succeed to return its intended result

Comment: Could u show me the code of authAPI.refreshToken() ?

Comment: @MinhKha `authAPI.refreshToken()` returns an axios promise which calls the authentication endpoint to refresh the tokens.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'm refreshing the token this way (updated OP's):

```js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { ApolloLink, Observable } from 'apollo-link';  // add Observable

// Define Http link
const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
  uri: '/my-graphql-endpoint',
  credentials: 'include'
});

// Add on error handler for apollo link

return new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
      // User access token has expired
      if (graphQLErrors && graphQLErrors[0].message === 'Unauthorized') {
        // We assume we have both tokens needed to run the async request
        if (refreshToken && clientToken) {
          // Let's refresh token through async request
          return new Observable(observer => {
            authAPI.requestRefreshToken(refreshToken, clientToken)
              .then(refreshResponse => {
                operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
                  headers: {
                    // Re-add old headers
                    ...headers,
                    // Switch out old access token for new one
                    authorization: `Bearer ${refreshResponse.access_token}` || null,
                  }
                }));
              })
              .then(() => {
                const subscriber = {
                  next: observer.next.bind(observer),
                  error: observer.error.bind(observer),
                  complete: observer.complete.bind(observer)
                };

                // Retry last failed request
                forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                // No refresh or client token available, we force user to login
                observer.error(error);
              });
          });
        }
      }
    })
  ])
});
```

Comment: I am trying to use this solution in a typescript project, but I get the error `Argument of type '({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }: ErrorResponse) => void | Observable<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorHandler'.`?

Comment: `observer` in `return new Observable(observer` is not defined

Answer (score 24):

Accepted answer is quite good but it wouldn't work with 2 or more concurrent requests. I've crafted the one below after testing different cases with my token renew workflow that fits my needs.

It's necessary to set `errorLink` before `authLink` in link pipeline.
`client.ts`

```js
import { ApolloClient, from, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client'

import errorLink from './errorLink'
import authLink from './authLink'
import cache from './cache'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
})

const apiClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache,
  credentials: 'include',
})

export default apiClient
```

Cache shared between 2 apollo client instances for setting user query when my renewal token is expired

`cache.ts`

```js
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

export default cache
```

`authLink.ts`

```js
import { ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client'

type Headers = {
  authorization?: string
}

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

  operation.setContext(({ headers }: { headers: Headers }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: accessToken,
    },
  }))

  return forward(operation)
})

export default authLink
```

`errorLink.ts`

```js
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, fromPromise } from '@apollo/client'

import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error'

import { GET_CURRENT_USER } from 'queries'
import { RENEW_TOKEN } from 'mutations'

import cache from './cache'

let isRefreshing = false
let pendingRequests: Function[] = []

const setIsRefreshing = (value: boolean) => {
  isRefreshing = value
}

const addPendingRequest = (pendingRequest: Function) => {
  pendingRequests.push(pendingRequest)
}

const renewTokenApiClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({ uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL }),
  cache,
  credentials: 'include',
})

const resolvePendingRequests = () => {
  pendingRequests.map((callback) => callback())
  pendingRequests = []
}

const getNewToken = async () => {
  const oldRenewalToken = localStorage.getItem('renewalToken')

  const {
    data: {
      renewToken: {
        session: { renewalToken, accessToken },
      },
    },
  } = await renewTokenApiClient.mutate({
    mutation: RENEW_TOKEN,
    variables: { input: { renewalToken: oldRenewalToken } },
  })!

  localStorage.setItem('renewalToken', renewalToken)
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)
}

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    for (const err of graphQLErrors) {
      switch (err?.message) {
        case 'expired':
          if (!isRefreshing) {
            setIsRefreshing(true)

            return fromPromise(
              getNewToken().catch(() => {
                resolvePendingRequests()
                setIsRefreshing(false)

                localStorage.clear()

                // Cache shared with main client instance
                renewTokenApiClient!.writeQuery({
                  query: GET_CURRENT_USER,
                  data: { currentUser: null },
                })

                return forward(operation)
              }),
            ).flatMap(() => {
              resolvePendingRequests()
              setIsRefreshing(false)

              return forward(operation)
            })
          } else {
            return fromPromise(
              new Promise((resolve) => {
                addPendingRequest(() => resolve())
              }),
            ).flatMap(() => {
              return forward(operation)
            })
          }
      }
    }
  }
})

export default errorLink
```

Comment: This solution is more complete and elegant.

Comment: I may be missing something, but what happens in case of `getNewToken()` failure? Catch block does not rethrow an error, we end up in the `flatMap` which in turn returns forwarded operation. 

The flow appears to be `someHttpRequestWhichRequiresAuth` -> 401 -> `getNewToken` -> 4xx or 5xx -> `someHttpRequestWhichRequiresAuth` (again) -> 401

It seems there's no point in rerunning `someHttpRequestWhichRequiresAuth` in case we couldn't refresh the token.

Comment: If getNewToken fails in some reason I just make a logout (clear localStorage and get currentUser: null. In 99% of cases it’s because renewalToken is expired. For me it’s sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand why the accepted solution wouldn't work with 2 or more concurrent requests. Do you just mean concurrent requests with the accepted solution would trigger multiple refreshes? If so, is that really problem enough to say it "won't work"?

Comment: You may have race conditions with 2 or more concurrent requests with accepted solution. I've got a case when I set new token on the first request headers then I set another new token on the second request and after that my first operation have been retried with already obsolete first token in headers. Thats what I've implemented more reliable solution

Comment: I'm still facing the `TypeError: retriedResult.subscribe is not a function` error, does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried with Observables without any wrapper like `fromPromise`, but neither that works. I'm kinda loosing my mind with this.

Comment: I managed to get this working. It is amazingly clear, thank you for posting it. I am unclear how renewTokenApiClient!.writeQuery is working in the middle of errorlink though. Do any useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER) then receive this data?

Answer (score 7):

We just had the same issues and after a very complicated solution with lots of Observeables we got a simple solution using promises which will be wrapped as an Observable in the end.

```
let tokenRefreshPromise: Promise = Promise.resolve()
let isRefreshing: boolean

function createErrorLink (store): ApolloLink {
  return onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      // this is a helper method where we are checking the error message
      if (isExpiredLogin(graphQLErrors) && !isRefreshing) {
        isRefreshing = true
        tokenRefreshPromise = store.dispatch('authentication/refreshToken')
        tokenRefreshPromise.then(() => isRefreshing = false)
      }
      return fromPromise(tokenRefreshPromise).flatMap(() => forward(operation))
    }
    if (networkError) {
      handleNetworkError(displayErrorMessage)
    }
  })
}
```

All pending requests are waiting for the tokenRefreshPromise and will then be forwarded.

Comment: This was great help

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me `apollo-client.ts`:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    if (
      graphQLErrors.some(({ extensions: { errorType } }) =>
        ['UNAUTHENTICATED', 'PERMISSION_DENIED'].includes(errorType as string)
      )
    ) {
      return fromPromise(fetch('/api/refresh', { method: 'POST' })).flatMap(
        () => forward(operation)
      )
    }
  }
  return forward(operation)
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql' })

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apollo client 3, you can simply use setContext for async operations:

```js
const retryLink = new RetryLink();

const refreshTokenLink = onError(({ networkError, forward, operation }) => {
        operation.setContext(async ({ headers = {} }) => {
           const token = await getNewToken();
            // optionally you can save in storage and let retryLink call the authLink again
            return {
              headers: {
                ...headers,
                Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
              },
            };
          } else {
             // logout
          }
        });

        return forward(operation);
});

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {

  const token = await getToken();

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: from([retryLink, refreshTokenLink, authLink, httpLink]),
});
```