# Apollo: Refetch Queries with Delay

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

Can I use refetchQueries with some delay. Can I set a delay or can I call refetchQueries in a function?
Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965347/how-to-execute-an-async-fetch-request-and-then-retry-last-failed-request/513210 ?

Comment: @HarshMakadia that answer seems to be about requesting failed queries, sometimes  we may wish to delay refetch if there are known latencies on the backend

Comment: @DamianGreen yeah, you are right

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find an elegant way to delay `refetchQueries`. Instead, I just modify the cache directly as mentioned farther down this section of the documentation. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#updating-after-a-mutation

Here's a snippet from my solution. The reason I loop through `sortPermutations` is that the query may have cached data for different sets of `variables`. This solution loops through all of them.

```js
const [createUser] = useMutation<AddUser, AddUserVariables>(ADD_USER, {
  update: (cache, { data }) => {
    if (!data?.addUser) return

    const cachedUsers = cache.readQuery<GetUsers>({
      query: GET_USERS,
      variables: sortedColumn,
    })

    sortPermutations.forEach(({ sortBy, sortOrder }) => {
      const users = [data.addUser, ...(cachedUsers?.users ?? [])].sort(
        sortUsers(sortBy, sortOrder),
      )

      cache.writeQuery<GetUsers, GetUsersVariables>({
        data: { users },
        query: GET_USERS,
        variables: { sortBy, sortOrder },
      })
    })
  },
})
```