# Apollo onError Observable fowarding not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable, apollo-client, react-apollo

it seems as if the request is not being retried.

- The refreshToken mutation **successfully** provides a new token
- This new token is then being **successfully** passed to the operation via the `operation.setContext()` function
- The `then()` function is being **successfully** called (catch does not activate)
- The request **does not get retried** and is being fullfilled with the same error "Signature has expired"

The idea is from [How to execute an async fetch request and then retry last failed request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965347/how-to-execute-an-async-fetch-request-and-then-retry-last-failed-request/51321068#51321068) and is the accepted answer.

```
const errorLink = onError(
  ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
        switch (err.message) {
          case "Signature has expired":
            return new Observable((observer) => {
              getNewToken()
                .then((token) => {
                  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
                    return {
                      headers: {
                        ...headers,
                        authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
                      },
                    };
                  });
                })
                .then(() => {
                  const subscriber = {
                    next: observer.next.bind(observer),
                    error: observer.error.bind(observer),
                    complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
                  };

                  forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // No refresh or client token available, we force user to login
                  observer.error(error);
                });
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Did you try the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386965/1577396) which seems to be better than the accepted answer?